# How to remove title from r-markdown pdf?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm new to r-markdown and latex. can someone help me to remove title from r-markdown. in place of title I want to insert an image. If I'm removing title not able to run r-markdown. so I kept an empty string as well so it's not working.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "author"
date: "27/04/2021"
output: pdf_document
---
```

Comment: perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46713491/13513328) helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rmarkdown: Turn off title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59668347/rmarkdown-turn-off-title)